# "No module named 'docx'" error but "requirement already satisfied" when I try to install

Tags: python, import, docx

From what I've read, it sounds like the issue might be that the module isn't in the same directory as my script. Is that the case? If so, how do I find the module and move it to the correct location?

**Edit**
In case it's relevant - I installed docx using easy_install, not pip.

Comment: Are you using virtual envs?  Are you trying to run your script with your virtual env activated?

Comment: I'm not sure what a virtual envs is. I've written my  code in sublime text and I'm calling it from the command line

Comment: Have you tried running your code using sublime?  My guess is sublime is using a different interpreter version than you have by default from your command line. Try Ctrl+B in sublime.

Comment: Thanks! Just tried that but still getting the same error: "no module named 'docx'"

Answer (score 2):

I use pycharm, created a project, you can choose which interpreter you want to use tu run your program, a common problem is having 2 interpreters and installing docx in one, and launching with the other interpreter. Also check the Lib included the packages of docx.

[Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDLNL.png)

Comment: i also had the same intepreter problem, thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

`pip show docx` 
This will show you where it is installed. However, if you're using python3 then
 `pip install python-docx` 
might be the one you need.

Answer (score 0):

Please install python-docx.
Then you import docx (not python-docx)